# Multiple parent classes targeting the same child using CSS only

Tags: css

I have three parent class elements that do the same thing. How can I write it out in one line.

Example: 
I want to make the following into one line:

```
.parent1 li > div.example> a span {color:red;}
.parent2 li > div.example> a span {color:red;}
.parent3 li > div.example> a span {color:red;}
```

Goal:

```
.parent1 li, .parent2 li, .parent3 li > div.example > a span {color:red;}
```

Note: I have spent numerous time searching Google, Bing, and Stack Overflow for a solution, but not able to find because I am not sure what I am asking for....

Comment: Why can't you just target it like so? `div.example > a span {color:red;}`? Is it necessary to declare the different `.parent` classes?

Comment: Please avoid using all caps for emphasis. It reads as yelling in some cultures.

Comment: Be careful with over-specific selectors: they can make refactoring CSS later more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions. Will not use all caps for emphasis as a future practise.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in such matter. You can only do something like this:

```
.parent1 li > div.example > a span,
.parent2 li > div.example > a span,
.parent3 li > div.example > a span {
  color:red;
}
```

And remove unnecesary whitespace characters (don't do this, please, minifier will take care of this for you):

```
.parent1 li > div.example > a span, .parent2 li > div.example > a span, .parent3 li > div.example > a span { color:red; }
```

Also, note that having such generic selectors (and such complex) are not considered to be a good practice (specificity is hard to manage and you have little control over what exactly will get styled) if you can, just add a class to `span` elements that you want to be styled differently.